# Erasing a Jenkins Enviroment Variable

Tags: jenkins, configuration, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I tried to delete an environment variable in the System Configuration. But when I click on both <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>Save</kbd>, no change ever happens.

The variable I want to delete is a variable that I edited to do some tests with the "**`Poll Mailbox Trigger`**" plugin.

Actually, no element that I modify in System Configuration seems to have an effect, can this be some error of the Jenkins version? I currently have the **`version 2.289.2.`**

I will show a step to step on how I try to delete the configuration:

[image: First Step of Configuration]

---

[image: Second Step of Configuration]

Hope it is clear and someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Can't confirm this behaviour in v2.289.3. If I Delete → Apply → F5 (Refresh) the variable is gone here.

Comment: Yeah I do not know why is it happening, as I said I could change the environment variable in the past. But now I can not. Btw, thanks for editing my post.